# Can't see partitions of USB flash drive in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I was copying data to an NTFS partition on a Verbatim 16 GB flash drive in Ubuntu 18.04. The copy ends successfully and I remove the USB drive properly. When I put it back in, the flash didn't mount.  I open the disks application and it shows under `/dev/sdb` with no other information and the only option allowed is edit mounting point. 
I run `gmesg` to check and this the message I got:

```
[  692.951220] usb 4-1.4: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  693.016212] usb 4-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=18a5, idProduct=0243, bcdDevice=10.75
[  693.016219] usb 4-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  693.016224] usb 4-1.4: Product: STORE N GO
[  693.016228] usb 4-1.4: Manufacturer: Verbatim
[  693.016232] usb 4-1.4: SerialNumber: 2553424620
[  693.017856] usb 4-1.4: Set SEL for device-initiated U1 failed.
[  693.017930] usb 4-1.4: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[  693.018083] usb-storage 4-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  693.018497] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1.4:1.0
[  694.045169] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Verbatim STORE N GO       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  694.046613] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  694.048076] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 2342.951253] usb 4-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 2351.650713] usb 4-1.4: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 2351.715941] usb 4-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=18a5, idProduct=0243, bcdDevice=10.75
[ 2351.715951] usb 4-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2351.715958] usb 4-1.4: Product: STORE N GO
[ 2351.715964] usb 4-1.4: Manufacturer: Verbatim
[ 2351.715969] usb 4-1.4: SerialNumber: 2553424620
[ 2351.717684] usb 4-1.4: Set SEL for device-initiated U1 failed.
[ 2351.717775] usb 4-1.4: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[ 2351.717965] usb-storage 4-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2351.718506] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1.4:1.0
[ 2352.733266] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Verbatim STORE N GO       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 2352.734444] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 2352.735664] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 5366.527818] usb 4-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 5586.937592] usb 4-1.4: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 5587.002204] usb 4-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=18a5, idProduct=0243, bcdDevice=10.75
[ 5587.002212] usb 4-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5587.002218] usb 4-1.4: Product: STORE N GO
[ 5587.002224] usb 4-1.4: Manufacturer: Verbatim
[ 5587.002228] usb 4-1.4: SerialNumber: 2553424620
[ 5587.003604] usb 4-1.4: Set SEL for device-initiated U1 failed.
[ 5587.003678] usb 4-1.4: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[ 5587.003895] usb-storage 4-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 5587.004444] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-1.4:1.0
[ 5588.029076] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Verbatim STORE N GO       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 5588.030100] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 5588.031145] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

How can I get my flash drive to work again? 
If nothing else, how can I read the files I put onto it?

`sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 14,5 MiB, 15208448 bytes, 29704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 140,7 MiB, 147496960 bytes, 288080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 3,7 MiB, 3878912 bytes, 7576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 34,6 MiB, 36216832 bytes, 70736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 91 MiB, 95408128 bytes, 186344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 2,3 MiB, 2355200 bytes, 4600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238,5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B720DB6A-0094-47E3-B220-CAE89D075F36

Device           Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624   2549759   1499136   732M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 2549760 500117503 497567744 237,3G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt: 237,3 GiB, 254752587776 bytes, 497563648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 236,3 GiB, 253675700224 bytes, 495460352 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: What does the command `lsblk` show?

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `sudo fdisk -l` in command line to see the result.
   In the result should be the name of your flash drive.
2. now edit your mount point with creating a directory:
   `sudo mkdir /media/name of your flash drive`
3. then type `sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/flashdrive` and your flashdrive should mount.

Comment: I do `sudo fdisk -l` but the usb is not listed

Comment: Actually, there should be something like /dev/sdb1 listed as your USB Device...

Comment: I add to my question the answer that `sudo fdisk -l` gave me.